# Human body with "skin peeled off" or "without skin"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

My art teacher used a word when describing a sculpture of a human without his skin (exposing muscle beneath). What was that word?

Comment: It was probably [flayed](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=flay&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=d4qdULK9A6jS0QWxx4GwAQ&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=7b36e5aac7eed2af&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=846)

Comment: ...but in a medical/anatomical teaching context they're usually called [muscular figures](http://www.scriphessco.com/products/dual-sex-muscular-figure/?sourcecode=SHSHOP)

Comment: Isn't it just 'anatomical model'?

Comment: I wonder why this question has be down-voted twice.

Comment: Good question. I have no idea what the four close-voters have been smoking.

Comment: Neither have I; I'm not sure I'd want any of it. The two upvoted answers so far indicate rare and unusual words I hadn't heard before.

Comment: "What word did my art teacher use" is not a widely useful question. This question has potential but needs to be rephrased so that it's generally useful.

Comment: Not sure why this became so controversial, but I'm the asker and I just wanted to say thanks to all for your help.

Comment: PS I am willing to rephrase the question to make it more appropriate. Sorry, new to the forum.

Comment: MετάEd, How is this any different than the questions where someone posts a photo and says, "What is this called?" (There's been numerous ones of those.) I don't understand how learning a new word is not constructive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found it. The word you're looking for is *ecorche*.

The [Wikipedia entry says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89corch%C3%A9)

> An écorché (French pronunciation: [ekɔʁʃe]) is a figure drawn, painted, or sculpted showing the muscles of the body without skin. Renaissance architect and theorist, Leon Battista Alberti recommended that when painters intend to depict a nude, they should first arrange the muscles and bones, then depict the overlying skin.

This [Wise Geek entry says:](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-ecorche.htm)

> An ecorche or “flayed figure” is a painted, drawn, or sculpted human figure depicted with the skin stripped away, exposing the underlying musculature. Medical texts may use ecorches for illustration so that students can clearly visualize the structures they are studying, but ecorches are most commonly used as references by artists. In some cases, they are also works of fine art in and of themselves, although they can be a bit macabre.
>
> The ecorche appears to date to around the 1400s, when several artists including Leonardo da Vinci started making such figures. Taboos against dissection often made it difficult to access human bodies, whether one was an artist wanting to create more accurate work or a medical student who wanted to learn about the body. da Vinci, along with many other artists, felt that it was important to understand the underlying architecture of the human body when depicting it in artwork, and ecorches assisted artists with this task.

Comment: Macabre is right. See [Damien Hirst's statue](http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c305/benodette/june%202006/Spring%202007/august%2007/Quater1%202008/StBartsHirst.jpg) of St Bartholomew (who was martyred by flaying) in [St Bartholomew's Church, Smithfield](http://www.achurchnearyou.com/album.php?V=15359).

Comment: Not sure why this became so controversial, but I'm the asker and I just wanted to say thanks to all for your help. THANKS JLG.

Comment: PS I am willing to rephrase the question to make it more appropriate. Sorry, new to the forum.

Answer (score 4):

It was a statue of a [flensed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flensed) human.

Also see: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flense

Comment: Also, WayfaringStranger, I'd give you a check-mark too if I could. I think technically you're also right and ecorche translates from french to flay / flense.